# Celery - Remote chain randomly hangs

Tags: python, celery, amqp

In a django project, as part of rather heavy import pipeline, i'm having to call three tasks that are part of a different codebase/application. Both applications point to the same AMQP broker and actually calling a task from the other app works great.

As part of our worklow, we want to chain those three tasks, and wait for the whole chain to return before proceeding (each task depends on the previous one, but we only care about the results of the last one). We have to call this chain for each item we're inserting in the DB. In order to try and speed up the process, i'm basically populating a dictionary with `AsyncResults` objects returned by calling `my_chain.apply_async` as we go to launch the task, and **then** iterate over this result dict to retrieve the data we need and further process it.

In pseudo code, this looks like this:

```py
def launch_chains():

    # assuming i need to preserve the order in which the chains are 
    # called for later processing
    result_dict = OrderedDict()     

    for item in all_items:

        # Need to use signature objects because the tasks are on a 
        # different app / codebase
        task_1 = remote_celery_app.signature(
            'path.to.my.task1',
            args=[whatever],
            queue="my_queue"
        )
        task_2 = remote_celery_app.signature(
            # ...
        )

        item_chain = celery.chain(
            task_1,
            task_2,
            app=remote_celery_app
        )

        result_dict[item.pk] = item_chain.apply_async()

    return result_dict

def process_items():

    remote_results = launch_chains()
    for item_id, r in remote_results:
        data = r.get()
        process_data(...)
```

On a rather small batch of items, this seemed to work fine, however when testing this with a heavier set (about 1600 objects, which is closer to what we'll need in production), the process loops ends up hanging on when calling `get`.

What happens seems pretty random: i'll usually get the very first result, and the second `get` call will hang indefinitely. Sometimes it won't even get the first results, and sometimes i'll manage to get about 30 responses (out of the expected 1600) (in those cases, the loop will actually terminate).

All tasks are launched and return data (i see the log on the remote app go when populating the dictionary), it's just when trying to grab the results that something goes wrong.

One way to fix this is to move the `apply_async` call to the processing loop, like this:

```
def launch_chains():

    # for loop, chain creation, etc...

        result_dict[item.pk] = item_chain       # removing the apply_async call...

    return result_dict

def process_items():

    remote_results = launch_chains()
    for item_id, r in remote_results:
        r = r.apply_async()                     # ... and adding it back here
        data = r.get()
        process_data(...)
```

This works perfecly, and i get to process all items, but it's obviously taking much longer, because i have to wait for **each** call to finish, while the previous version should allow me to starts iterating over results that were returned while still populating my result dict.

When playing around in a python shell, what usually happens is that the first chain I try to process (no matter if it's the first one that got launched of another one picked randomly) will be in a `SUCCESS` state, and then all other will permanently remain `PENDING`.

I've been able to reproduce the behaviour by creating a dummy task on the remote app, and calling it with the following management command:

```
# remote_app.tasks.py
def add(*args):
    return sum(args)
    # simulating some processing delay. 
    # Removing this does not fix the problem
    time.sleep(random.random())

# test_command.py
l1 = [
    [2, 2],
    [3, 3],
]
l2 = [
    [4, 4],
    [6, 6],
]

def get_remote_chain(i):
    """ 
    Call the tasks remotely. This seems to work fine whith a small number 
    of calls, but ends up hanging when i start to call it a bunch.  
    Behaviour is basically the same as described above.
    """
    t1 = remote_app.signature(
        'remote.path.to.add',
        args=l1[i],
        queue='somequeue'
    )
    t2 = remote_app.signature(
        'remote.path.to.add',
        args=l2[i],
        queue='somequeue'
    )

    return celery.chain(
        t1, t2, app=simi_app
    )


def get_local_chain(i):
    """
    I copy pasted the task locally, and tried to call this version of the 
    chain instead:
    Everything works fine, no matter how many times we call it
    """
    return celery.chain(
        add.s(*l1[i]),
        add.s(*l1[i]),
    )


def launch_chains():

    results = OrderedDict()
    for i in range(100):
        for j in range(2):

            # task_chain = get_local_chain(j)
            task_chain = get_remote_chain(j)

            results['%d-%d' % (j, i)] = task_chain.apply_async()

    return results

class Command(BaseCommand):


    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        results = launch_chains()
        print('dict ok')

        for rid, r in results.items():
            print(rid, r.get())

        # Trying an alternate way to process the results, trying to 
        # ensure we wait until each task is ready.
        # Again, this works fine with local tasks, but ends up hanging, 
        # apparently randomly, after a few remote ones have been "processed".
        #
        # rlen = len(results)
        # while results:
        #     for rid, r in results.items():
        #         if r.ready():
        #             print(rid, r.status)
        #             print(r.get())
        #             results.pop(rid)
        #     if len(results) != rlen:
        #         print('RETRYING ALL, %d remaining' % len(results))
        #         rlen = len(results)
```

I'll admit i'm don't know celery and AMQP that much, so i have no idea if this is a configration problem of if i'm "doing it wrong". However, since it works fine locally, i'm pretty sure the problem comes from the communication between the two apps.

I'm using celery 3.1.16 on the django app, and the remote app is 4.0.2... For a whole bunch of reasons i can't upgrade on the django side, not sure if i'll be able to downgrade on remote one (a quick try breaks because the code uses various new things from 4.0).

Any ideas ? Do not hesitate to ask for more config info if needed, can't think of anything more right now.